# How to pass array as an argument to server method via jQuery+Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Well I am developing a web application in Asp.Net and in the code behind I am using C#. I've successfully written code to pass a class object to code behind method but I am wondering how to pass an array as an argument via ajax and jQuery.

I've tried something but it didn't work. Here is my code what I am trying to run

```
function Test(){
var argu = [1, 2];
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'MyPage.aspx/Foo',
        data: '{args: ' + argu + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           // Success
        },
        error: function (response) {
           // Failed
        }
      });
}
```

And this is my code behind method which is written in C#.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static bool Foo(int[] args)
{
   return true;
}
```

Application built successfully. I have put break points but my code behind method doesn't fire. I am wondering Where is the problem? What else I am missing here?

Comment: .You have to include [HttpPost]  along with [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod] .Also Can you try chaning 'url':'@Url.Content(<ControllerName>,'Foo') and check if atleast it reaches the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all code seems good enough to make a call but I think the problem is in passing the `data` in your code.

It should be like.

```
data: '{args: ' + JSON.Stringify(argu) + '}'
```

And finally your code should be like

```
function Test(){
var argu = [1, 2];
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'MyPage.aspx/Foo',
        data: '{args: ' + JSON.Stringify(argu) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           // Success
        },
        error: function (response) {
           // Failed
        }
      });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the problem?

What you are sending is not valid JSON and that's what you are telling `$ajax` to send when you set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

JSON requires double quotes for keys and for string values

Don't try creating JSON manually ... use language built in serializers

Try changing:

```
data: '{args: ' + argu + '}',
```

To

```
data: JSON.stringify({args:  argu }),
```

Note:   Seems you are expecting `int` in server code. Looks suspicious when you are sending an object structure

Answer (score 1):

Why no simply set the array value to data and do the post ?

```
function Test(){
var argu = [1, 2];
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'MyPage.aspx/Foo',
        data: argu,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           // Success
        },
        error: function (response) {
           // Failed
        }
      });
}
```

You can use `JSON.stringify([1,2])` to send the entire data as a string to the backend, get the data as a string (rather than int[]) and deserialize of parse it back to int[]

Comment: $.ajax will still serialize using `$.param` and send as form encoded doing it this way